# Android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

i tried to run a sample hello world app in android studio, i have installed x86 emulator in my PC.
If i run, i will get an error saying Hardware acceleration is required.

Here is the full error,

```
emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I'm using windows 8 & i have got the latest version of Android studio, may i know what is the issue?

thanks

Comment: Use Genymotion emulator instead, it's much better.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK Directory and find **intel** directory inside **extras**

> C:\Users\Pradyuma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Install **intelhaxm-android.exe** from that directory and restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional (fast) hardware based emulator provided by Intel. You can get it from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
Note - if you still have issues after installing do these things

Turn off Avast or other anti virus.  For Avast:  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting.

Set vt on in bios  and turn off M/S hypervisor by typing 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Set ND bit on by typing
            bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

### restart

Comment: Hi, actually i tried to install tat accelerator software, it says that vt is not enabled, can you tell me how can i turn it on?

Comment: i somehow enabled the `VT` on my computer bios, but i'm not getting any console in bios to turn off `M/S hypervisor`. also can you tell me how to set ND bit there in bios. where is the console in bios i'm not getting

Comment: Don't worry about IOS - try using the two bcedit command lines and see what happens